# PHP Split array at space before certain qty of characters

Tags: php

I have an application that can only deal with text up to 100 characters in length per line.

However I do not want to be splitting mid-word in a sentence as that doesn't look very nice. Therefore we would need to find the space before the 100th Character and then add it into the array.

I was thinking using strrpos would work - but am unsure how to do the continuing so it has everything in one array

```
$textToDraw = 'this is a message that is over 100 characters long just to see how well that the breaks work';
$characterLimit = substr($textToDraw, 0, 100);
$textBeforeLimit = strrpos($characterLimit, ' ', 0);
```

Thanks

UPDATE. This is the current code I have to split the text into an array and then draw each line. However I need it to cut on the space before 100 characters - and not on a hardcoded 100 character limit.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($textToDraw); $i++) {
    $splitPoint = 100;
    if ( strlen($textToDraw[$i]) > $splitPoint ) {
        $newTextLines = str_split($textToDraw[$i], $splitPoint);
        array_splice($textToDraw, $i, 1, $newTextLines);
        $i = $i + count($newTextLines) - 1;
    }
}
foreach ($textToDraw as $actualTextToDraw) {
    $page->drawText($actualTextToDraw, $this->x , $this->y , 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: I don't want to word wrap - as the application works on pixels - and cannot detect new lines. I need it to be able to output it as variables in an array. - or at least be able to count how many lines it outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

*Wraps a string to a given number of characters using a string break character.*

Example adapted from the documentation page:

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;

// Outputs:
// The quick brown fox<br />
// jumped over the lazy<br />
// dog.
```

**Update for new info in question:**

Apply it to your needs:

```
$text = "Here's some example text that may or may not be really really long.";
$linedText = wordwrap($text, 20, "\n");
$lines = explode("\n", $linedText);

// Do whatever with $lines.
```

Comment: If you need it as an array, then just capture the output of `wordwrap()` and split it on the new line character with `explode();`.

Comment: Thanks - $lines returns just one item in that array though - rather than each line as a new element in that array

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) as below. This Wraps a string to a given number of characters using a string break character.

```
<?php
$textToDraw = 'this is a message that is over 100 characters long just to see how well that the breaks work';

$newtext = wordwrap($textToDraw, 100, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - Apologies I forgot to say in my question - that I need it as an array and not wordwrap using br. Thanks